# put libraries inside exe folder in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, portability

I'm trying to make a portable Linux application where all required libraries are included inside the folder.
But if I just put them in the folder next to the executables, it saiys it cant find the libraries.
So how can I ship an application that contains all required libaries inside one folder?

Comment: Lookup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: yeah but I'd have to set it for every PC I'd like to run the application on. isn't there a way around this?

Comment: _"isn't there a way around this?"_ None I'm aware of.

Comment: so everytime i run the application, I have to manually set an environment variable? or is there a way to use a script that sets the variable to ther current path and starts the app, that i can use without root?

Comment: You installation script should put it in the user's or machine's startup profile.

Comment: Applications like google earth that rely on their own set of libs use to start the real binary with a bash script "in front".

Comment: Thx, I put a script that sets the librarypath in front, it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to make a portable Linux application where all required libraries are included inside the folder.

What you are looking for is a binary with `RPATH` that contains `$ORIGIN`. For example, building your binary with:

```
gcc -o myexe main.o ... '-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/'
```

(note: single quotes are *required*.) will result in `myexe` looking for shared libraries in the same directory in which the binary itself was found.